# Reliable correction of broken words

Tags: nltk

I have a text as an in put, wh ere ther e are occassi on aly brok en wor ds.

Is there a function in `NLTK` or similar that could return the output as

`I have a text as an input, where there are occassionaly broken words.`?

Comment: You can get pretty close with the use of a dictionary from [`pyechant`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/) and a little bit of looping. But you will still encounter issues with `occasi on ally` because you can have both `occasionally` and `occasion` and `ally`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get everything in one function, but you can do with the help of Pyenchant library to check spellings of words. These steps you can do:

1. Take the sentence
2. Tokenize words using nltk word tokenizer
3. Check each in the dictionary provided by pyEnchant
4. If that word is in dictionary, means word is correct, else get suggested words related to that word using function provided by pyEnchant
5. Compute minimum edit distance(levenshtein distance) between incorrect word and each suggested word
6. Take the word with minimum distance

Yes, I will not say it performs efficiently, because pyEnchant dictionary contains lot of words that do not seems legal, but it works in some cases.

Above method is using Levenshtein distance, you can also do spell correction using Ngrams, jaccard coefficient also.

I already implemented this task, you can check on my gitHub link(https://github.com/rameshjesswani/Semantic-Textual-Similarity/blob/master/nlp_basics/nltk/string_similarity.ipynb)